# How can I store Datastore Query to memcache in Go AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I'm working on Appengine with Golang.

I have about 1000 entities on datastore.

When I query all entities(`q.GetAll(...)`), `Datstore Read Operations` or `Datastore Small Operations` run about 2% usage(1k of 50k).
It's same when I use `KeysOnly()` or `Project(..something...)`.

I have read some articles to solve this, *I have to store Datastore Query to memcache*.
But I cannot find how to do that.

So how can I store/retrieve Datastore Query to/from memcache in Go AppEngine?

Or is there other way to decrease datastore read/small operation usage?

I need your help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to make a query with `KeysOnly()` and caching each call `datastore.Get()` for the key.

The algorithm is as follows:

- after adding entity, add it to the cache by her own key
- in obtaining check it in cache

  - if no, then get out it from datastore and add it back into the cache
  - if there is use it from cache

How to use memcache described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/memcache/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I made a query with 'KeysOnly()', 'Datastore Small Operation' spend 2% usage again. Is that right?

`q := datastore.NewQuery("Greeting").KeysOnly()`
`keys, _ := q.GetAll(c, nil)`

Comment: 'Datastore Small Operation' spent when you call `datastore.Get(c, key, &dst`), not on query, therefore you need caching this part of your code. Just create a wrapper for the function `datastore.Get`. There is my pseudocode: [gist](https://gist.github.com/lapteuh/3ea8d6d301cc406ae36d).

Answer (score 0):

Queries are not cached.  If your entity are small, you can reduce use a [projection query](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/projectionqueries) and reduce to [small costs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/pricing#costs-for-datastore-calls).  Check out the [end of the article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/projectionqueries#Go_Indexes_for_projections) for information about generating the necessary search index.